# How to hide function name and controller name from url in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

My Yii app url format is domain/controller/function. I don't want to disclose the original controller name and function to user.The user should see only domain/foo/bar instead of original names.How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can archive it by using url manager.
Imagine you have a controller called "SampleController" with an action called "actionSampless", then you can have something like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path','showScriptName'=>false, 'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
    'test/test/*'=>'Sample/Sampless',
     //'pattern1'=>'route1', (it goes like this)
   ),
  ),
```

for more info [click here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url). read **User-friendly URLs** topic..

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

inside the application configuration
i.e in config/main.php

add the line to url rules

```
'foo/bar'=>'ur_controller_name/ur_action_name',
```